# Excecuting svn commit during SBT build

Tags: scala, svn, sbt

I'm looking at coming up with a release process using the sbt release plugin, but I am getting an error when I try to commit to SVN as a release step.

> svn: Commit failed (details follow):
>   svn: '/tmp/checkout/svn-test/commit' is not under version control

"/tmp/checkout/svn-test/" is the correct path to my project. I suspect I'm doing something wrong when I define the ReleaseStep to commit to SVN:

My build.sbt release config is as follows:

```
lazy val execScript = taskKey[Unit]("Commit to Subversion")

execScript := {
  "svn commit -m 'test commit from release plugin'" !
}

val commitToSVN = () => ReleaseStep(
  action = releaseStepTask(execScript)
)

releaseProcess := Seq[ReleaseStep](
  ReleaseTransformations.checkSnapshotDependencies,
  ReleaseTransformations.inquireVersions,
  ReleaseTransformations.setReleaseVersion,
  commitToSVN()
)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your project is in `/tmp`? If so I would move it out of there, [it is often cleaned out on every boot](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html).

Comment: It's there for just now, I did a fresh checkout there then ran the release goal in SBT. I did try in a different directory as well but I still get a "[project-path]/commit is not under version control" error

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is the use of shell syntax (namely the use of single quotes) with `!`. Does it work if you do `Seq("svn", "commit", "-m", ...)` instead? As you have it, I think it thinks that `'test` and `commit` and `from` and `release` and `plugin'` are all separate arguments.

Comment: @SethTisue That was exactly it. Just tested it with a single word commit message and it worked fine. Thanks, you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be the use of shell syntax, namely the use of single quotes, with `!`. As you have it, it thinks that `'test` and `commit` and `from` and `release` and `plugin'` are all separate arguments.

The Java `Process` stuff, which Scala methods like `!` are just thin wrappers for, don't run the process using a shell, and therefore shell syntax doesn't apply.

It should work if you do `Seq("svn", "commit", "-m", ...)` instead. Passing the arguments separately means you won't need single quotes to delimit arguments.